# How To Apply A Common Method To Multiple Objects

Tags: java, swing

I Have got a number of similar objects in in a jFrameForm and i want to apply a common method to all of them... to save time is there any way to apply that method to all of them at once without the use of lists?

Comment: would you provide come code examples of your project? (about common method)

Comment: Do asynchronous calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use refletion:

```
private void commonMethod() throws IllegalAccessException {
    Field[] fields = this.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field field : fields) {
        if (field.getType().isAssignableFrom(MyClass.class)) {
            Object o = field.get(this);
            //Do whatever with o
        }
    }
}
```